# Identifying unknown LCD pins

Tags: lcd, identification

I have an LCD module (from a mobile phone) with unknown pins. It has 40 pins and is labelled with this number: "TP-Y0100-c0".

Can anybody help me to identify the pins? I want to use it with microcontroller

Comment: Maybe a photo of the module in question. You might have more luck searching on the phone model and seeing if other hackers have used parts from it. You might have to simply reverse-engineer the pins as best you can.

Answer (score 2):

Random LCDs are notoriously hard to reverse engineer, and not worth it unless you have a stack of 10,000 of them. Consider using a more common part with lots of support, like a Nokia 5110, 1602 LCD, or one of the many modules that are brought up with a quick search on eBay. These are dirt cheap, have pre-written drivers, and are going to actually work.

If you're dead set on reverse engineering it, I would start here http://www.eevblog.com/forum/projects/reverse-engineering-lcd-from-ipod-nano-v6/ to learn what you're up against.